# c# Sorting a Custom List

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, object

I have the following list:

```
public class Address{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
}

List<Address> MyAddressList = new List<Address>();
```

and what I want to do is sort this list by Suburb and then Street.
I have seen that I can sort by one of the properties (Suburb in this case):

```
MyAddressList = MyAddressList.OrderBy( x => x.Suburb ).ToList();
```

but I want to sort by Suburb then Street.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can chain further ordering by using ThenBy (or ThenByDescending) calls:

```
MyAddressList = MyAddressList.OrderBy( x => x.Suburb ).ThenBy(x => x.Street).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use ThenBy

> Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby.aspx

```
MyAddressList = 
   MyAddressList.OrderBy( x => x.Suburb ).ThenBy(x => x.Street).ToList();
```

If needed, you can also [chain multiple ThenBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760001/linq-orderby-versus-thenby).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the `Comparison` delegate like this:

```
private int CompareAddress(Address first, Address second)
{
    if (first.Suburb.Equals(second.Suburb))
    {
        return first.Street.CompareTo(second.Street);
    }
    else
    {
        return first.Suburb.CompareTo(second.Suburb);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
List<Address> MyAddressList = new List<Address>();
MyAddressList.Sort(CompareAddress);
```