# OrderBy on List with DynamicProxies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In controller I have a query and its result will be displayed in the View.

This is how the query result model looks like:

```
    public class Timesheet
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int TimesheetId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual int TimesheetWeek { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual DateTime TimesheetWeekStarts { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual DateTime TimesheetWeekEnds { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual string TimesheetOwner { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<TimesheetEntry> TimesheetEntries { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the TimesheetEntry model:

```
public class TimesheetEntry
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int EntryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual double TotalHours { get; set; }

    public Timesheet Timesheet { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project number")]
    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

The query will always return only one Timesheet class, with multiple TimesheetEntries.
Usually I would expect the number of entries to be certain number. Lets say in this case it should be 56. So if the

```
    TimesheetEntries.Count() != 56
```

I will add additional entries manually to the query result to ensure that the number of entries is as required.
Once done, I will order entries by Date.

```
    TimesheetEntries.OrderBy(x => x.EntryDate).OrderBy(x => x.Project);
```

Some Pseudo code to show the process which got me to my problem:

```
public void PseudoCode()
    {
        const int REQUIRED_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES = 45;

        //this will return only one instance of model due to .FirstOrDefault()
        var result = this.db.Timesheets.Where(x => x.TimesheetWeekStarts <= DateTime.Now).Select(x => x)
            .Where(x => x.TimesheetOwner == User.Identity.Name)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            //if number of entries is not what I expect
            if(result.TimesheetEntries.Count() < REQUIRED_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES)
            {
                //check how many to add
                int entriesMissing = REQUIRED_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES - result.TimesheetEntries.Count();

                //add missing entries as empty entries
                for (int i = 0; i < entriesMissing; i++)
                {
                    result.TimesheetEntries.Add(
                        new TimesheetEntry
                        {
                            //to shorten this I am only adding DateTime.Now, normaly different times/dates would be added
                            EntryDate = DateTime.Now,
                            TotalHours = 8
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        result.TimesheetEntries.OrderBy(x => x.EntryDate).OrderBy(x => x.ProjectId);
    }
```

Here is the result of sorting:

[image: Sorting result]

so the the list contains ordered DynamicProxies first and then ordered manually added entries.

But the order should have been:

1. DynamicProxies.TimesheetEntry
2. TimesheetEntry
3. TimesheetEntry
4. DynamicProxies.TimesheetEntry
   ... etc

Why is this? Why the order result is ordered this way?
Or am I doing this completely wrong ...

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say you were calling that `OrderBy`, *then* adding the "missing" `TimesheetEntries`. That would just append them to the sorted proxies and look like what you're seeing. You haven't posted much relevant code so it's purely a guess though. There's nothing special about proxies that wouldn't allow them to be sorted like any other object.

Comment: thank you, but no. I am adding the entries and them they are sorted...

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Without it, anyone else attempting to answer this question will only be able to make guesses at the problem. Please take a look at this link, particularly the "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example" section: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added some extra code as requested. thank you, should have done this on the beginning.

Comment: At least one of the issues is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760001/linq-orderby-versus-thenby). You should not use multiple `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `OrderBy` does not sort the set, it *returns* a sorted `IEnumerable`. If you want the collection to reflect the `OrderBy` operation, you have to assign back to it like so:

```
result.TimesheetEntries = result.TimesheetEntries
                                .OrderBy(x => x.EntryDate)
                                .ThenBy(x => x.ProjectId)
                                .ToList();
```

Edit - Also, as pointed out by smartcaveman, if you want to sort by multiple columns you should use `ThenBy`'s for all subsequent ordering after the first `OrderBy`. If you don't use `ThenBy()`, each `OrderBy()` will continue to re-baseline the sort on the current `OrderBy` field.

Comment: It seems like your second `OrderBy` should be a `ThenBy`

Comment: Thank you. I will run few test to play with this.