# Lambda expression for sorting list of collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

My  input is  below  xml file

```
<Employees>
  <Department Position="9">
   <Employee No="7" Status="True" />
   <Employee No="6" Status="True" />
   <Employee No="8" Status="True" />
</Department>
<Department Position="4">
  <Employee No="7" Status="True" />
  <Employee No="8" Status="True" />
  <Employee No="6" Status="True" />
</Department>
</Employees>

Out put should  be  sorted  by department position  and  employee  "No"


<Employees>
 <Department Position="4">
  <Employee No="6" Status="True" />
  <Employee No="7" Status="True" />
  <Employee No="8" Status="True" />
 </Department>
 <Department Position="9">
   <Employee No="6" Status="True" />
   <Employee No="7" Status="True" />
   <Employee No="8" Status="True" />
 </Department>
```

I  have added below code but it returns either "position" wise or "No" wise but not both.

```
var sortSignalList = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

sortSignalList.OrderBy(x => x.Position).OrderBy(x=>x.No).ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ OrderBy versus ThenBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760001/linq-orderby-versus-thenby)

Answer (score 4):

```
sortSignalList.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ThenBy(x=>x.No).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try....

```
sortSignalList.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ThenBy(x=>x.No).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

List can also be Sorted **ThenByDescending**

```
var thenByDescResult =sortSignalList.OrderBy(s => s.Position).ThenByDescending(s => s.No);
```