# Dynamic LINQ discards applied OrderBy sortings except the latest applied

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, .net-core

Suppose I have a sequence of objects that I want to sort using the names of its properties, e.g. sequence `IQueryable<T>` to be sorted first by property `A`, then `B`, then `C`. I have the following code:

```
    using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

    IQueryable<T> source = ...
    var properties = new[]{"A","B","C"};
    foreach (var property in properties.Reverse())
    {
        source = source.OrderBy(property);
    }
    return source;
```

The resulting code returns `source` sorted only by the latest applied property (i.e. `A` in this case) disregarding all the previous orderings. Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: you should use ThenBy on IOrderedEnumerable (which is returned by OrderBy extension), if you want to sort on multiple fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ OrderBy versus ThenBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760001/linq-orderby-versus-thenby)

Comment: Yes, thank you. `ThenBy` requires `IOrderedQueryable`, that’s why IntelliSence did not see it.