# Difference between using consecutive OrderBy()'s instead of ThenBy()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, ienumerable

I am confused as to why these two pieces of code creates two different results. I would expect the second one, using ThenBy() to generate the correct result, but it does not. The first one (something I tried during debugging) creates the right result (But it seems to be by coincidence).

I want it to order like this:

Order everything by the property "FileDate" in descending order. Then order the items that are of the event type (using .IsEvent() extension) by it's "FileDate" by ascending order. Then, order it by name, so items that has the same date is ordered alphabetically.

```
var firstSort = nodeList.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileDate);
var secondSort = firstSort.OrderBy(x => x.IsEvent() ? x.FileDate : DateTime.MinValue);
var thirdSort = secondSort.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

The result in thirdSort is the correct result. The result i expect. But it's a bad piece of code I think.

```
var sortedSet = nodeList.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileDate)
                .ThenBy(x => x.IsEvent() ? x.FileDate : DateTime.MinValue)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                .Skip(amountToSkip).Take(pageSize);
```

This does not create the result i expect. But I like that piece of code more.

Can someone ILI5 why these create different results? And also how I get the right result, not using consecutive OrderBy() calls.

Here is some example data, the result, and the expected result:

Format: Name (Type) (FileDate)

Input (nodeList):

- An exciting event (Event type) (24-11-2023)
- Another event (Event type) (16-11-2023)

Result:

- An exciting event (Event type) (24-11-2023)
- Another event (Event type) (16-11-2023)

Expected result:

- Another event (Event type) (16-11-2023)
- An exciting event (Event type) (24-11-2023)

Comment: It is hard to answer that question without you showing the input data and telling us what the expected result is.

Comment: Touché. I will see what I can gather.

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: I have added some example data in the question.

Comment: If the result is as expected as you say then `OrderBy(x => x.Name)` was already sufficient and you can remove the OrderBy clauses before that. OrderBy will not respect previous ordering of the list it will just reorder the list according to its own rule. Your sample does not help as it does not show what should happen with name.

Comment: Which element is your first comprare ?

Comment: The first code with each ordering rule overwrites the ordering behavior from the previous one. Thus the final ordering rule for the first code will be ordering by `FileName`. For the second code, the data will be ordered by `FileDate`. If there are data that have same `FileDate`, then those data will be ordered by next criteria. If the the data have the same value for next criteria, those data will be sorted with next next criteria and so on. At the end of the result, the data with latest  `FileDate` will be on the top.

Comment: @Ralf But I want it to work like this: Order everything by the property "FileDate" in descending order. Then order the items that are of the event type (using .IsEvent() extension) by ascending order. The, order it by name, so items that has the same date is ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @YongShun Oh, so it's actually a coincidence that the result of the first code works? Because the important part of the search is the FileDate property.

Comment: I assumed `Name` is in string type, how could you get the expected result in that order with the `thirdSort`? https://dotnetfiddle.net/m2mil3 Have you tested your example data?

Comment: @shingo By a coincidence.

Comment: But your expected result shows the earliest `FileDate` as first, so it conflicts that you want your data to be ordered by latest `FileDate`.

Comment: The date property in the expected result is sorted in **ascending order**, but you commented "Order everything by the property "FileDate" in **descending order**". So the example is wrong.

Comment: @YongShun The question has been answered below. The problem was not what I though it was.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ OrderBy versus ThenBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760001/linq-orderby-versus-thenby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ThenBy` is used when the primary order value is the same. You first order by date, and if the date is the same, then you order these values by name.

OrderBy on the other hand just do a completely new sort, even it it is stable.

In your example there are no cases where either the date or the name is the same.So your example that uses OrderBy will in effect only order by name. And your ThenBy example will only order by date, descending.

So the result is completely as expected, even if I'm not sure what result you actually want.

#### Example:

Say I have objects composed of pairs of letters and numbers, say `a2, b2, a1, c1`. And we use `OrderBy` first for letter and then for number we would get `a1, c1, a2, b2`. The reason is that we produce the intermediate sorting of `a2, a1, b2, c1`, and then do a stable sort of that.

Using OrderBy letter, and ThenBy number will produce `a1, a2, b2, c1`, since it will only use the number for ordering if the letter is the same.